# UIControl in UITextField.rightView doesnot call actions for controlEvents

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicontrol

I placed a UIControl in a UIView,and set the UIView as the UITextField.rightView,but the UIControl then doesnot call actions for controlEvents I added like:[control addTarget:self action:@selector(searchButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside].If I change the UIControl to a UIButton, it works well, but I has to use UIControl for some reason.Any one know the reason and solution?
I'm using xcode 14.0 on iOS 16.1

```
import UIKit
class DemoControl: UIControl { }
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(searchBar)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let searchView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: demoControl.frame.width, height: demoControl.frame.height))
    searchView.addSubview(demoControl)
    searchBar.searchTextField.rightViewMode = .always
    searchBar.searchTextField.rightView = searchView
}

private lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let view = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 24, height: 36))
    return view
}()

private lazy var demoControl: DemoControl = {
    let control = DemoControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 52, height: 24))
    control.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    control.backgroundColor = .red
    control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(controlAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return control
}()

private lazy var demoButton: UIButton = {
    let control = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 52, height: 24))
    control.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    control.backgroundColor = .red
    control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(controlAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return control
}()

@objc private func controlAction() {
    print("Click!!!")
}
```

}

Comment: Keep in mind that `UIControl` is not meant to be used directly. You are supposed to use something that extends `UIControl`. The documentation for `UIControl` states *"You don’t create instances of this class directly. The UIControl class is a subclassing point that you extend to implement custom controls"*.

Comment: @HangarRash Yes,actually I used a custom control extends UIControl, not directly an instance of UIControl, but that doesnot make any difference.This control works well if is not placed in the UITextField.rightView

Comment: Without seeing the code for your custom control and the code that sets up the text field it will be very difficult for anyone to point out the issue. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks I have added a demo, please take a look

Comment: Interesting. I overrode all of the "tracking" methods of `UIControl` in the `DemoControl` class and the `beginTracking` is called and returns `true` but then the `cancelTracking` is called which is why the event is never sent. So something in the text field is cancelling the tap event. Not sure what allows `UIButton` to succeed while `DemoControl` fails. And, as you said, `DemoControl` works just fine outside of the text field.

Comment: Yeah,that's quiet weird